# How to mock a "template<class T> QSharedPointer<T>" class function with gmock

Tags: googletest, googlemock

i am trying to mock a class function that is a

```
template<class T> QSharedPointer<T>
```

I checked a bit on StackOverflow but others examples are **really complicated**.
Here is my class function:

```
template<class T> QSharedPointer<T> getObjectWithId ( int id )
{
    QSharedPointer<SqlObject> obj = getObjectWithId ( T::staticMetaObject.className(), id );
    return qSharedPointerCast<T> ( obj );
}
```

I would like to mock this function like this

```
class MockingSqlConnector : public SqlObjectFactory
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD ( auto, getObjectWithId, ( int id ), ( override ) );
};
```

I get the error: **overloaded function "SqlObjectFactory::getObjectWithId" is not a type name**

Comment: You won't be able to mock template method. In order to have `getObjectWithId` mocked with `MOCK_METHOD`, you'd have to make it a virtual method in the base class or use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426067/how-to-mock-templated-methods-using-google-mock.

Comment: You can make whole MockingSqlConnector class templated by T, in that case MOCK_METHOD would return QSharedPointer<T>. But that will not work in case you have multiple templated methods with different types.